# Create a total for attribute not in report

Tags: cognos

I have created for my user a crosstab report that represents a summary of average test times for electronic components. The attributes are:

```
COMPONENT, WEEKTEST BEGIN DATE, TEST NAME, AUTOTESTER SOFTWARE VERSION, TEST TIME IN SECS, AVG TEST TIME IN SECS
```

This is my crosstab layout

```
                                   WEEKTEST BEGIN DATE
    COMPONENT TESTNAME AUTOTESTERSW TOTAL(AVG TEST TIME IN SECS)
TOTAL BY COMPONENT
```

When I add a total to my report, It adds all the records for average test time() as you would expect. However my user wants the total to be for Test Time In Seconds instead.

I tried modifying the Total calculation from "total(currentMeasure within detail [COMPONENT])" to "total(currentMeasure within set [COMPONENT])" but the results made no sense.

I also tried changing the calculation  to "total(currentMeasure within set [TEST TIME IN SECS])" but it failed: Report Studio threw an error because this attribute is not in the report (even though it is in the query).

Can this be done at all?

Cognos Report Studio 8.4
IBM DB2 UDB

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by _total to be for Test Time In Seconds_ ? Do you have 'Test Time in Seconds'? It's strange to me that you want a total - wouldn't you want the aggregate average? Are you saying you want the summary to be in seconds, not in hh:mm:ss format?

Comment: Data format here is not in question. The aggregated average is what reportstudio calculates by default. My user requested a total to be for Test Time In Seconds (in my query, not my report) to give him "a baseline of performance".

Comment: I used "total(currentMeasure within set [TESTTIMESECS])" for my total calculation and it solved my problem after adding TESTTIMESECS to my report. I am currently waiting on my user to confirm.